# Have a recommendation for a good resource on infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does anyone know of a good resource (e.g. book, paper) for learning about the foundations of the infinite series?

Comment: Bromwich's book *Infinite Series* would seem like a sensible starting point...

Answer (score 1):

Any decent calculus textbook is a good start.

Answer (score 1):

I like Stewart's calculus section on series (chapter 11). Some of the regular problems are great and some of the problems in the "problems plus" section are fantastic.

In my opinion, you get a good sense of series by doing lots of manipulations/calculations. Stewart is great for that.

Comment: Agree. I had Stewart in mind actually. The problems in Chapter 11 of his book are very good. Some are often seen as problems in textbooks on real analysis.

Comment: @Nunya indeed. They can get quite tricky